# What is the metal that was melted in episode 1?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In episode 1 of *The Mandalorian*, the protagonist is given a chunk of metal that he then takes to another Mandolorian who melts it down and makes a shoulder piece for him.

What is this metal, and why does it seem so special to the Mandolorians?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beskar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This is called Beskar.

This metal is used to make Mandalorian armor and can withstand blaster fire.

This [Esquire](https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/movies/a29773587/beskar-the-mandalorian-armor-explained/) article explains its importance for Mandalorians (emphasis mine).

> This substance is described as "an alloy used in Mandalorian armor, notable for its high tolerance to extreme forms of damage. The metal was durable enough to withstand a direct blaster shot, and could potentially withstand the slash or glancing blow of a lightsaber, though could be penetrated with a direct stab."
>
> **This armor is worn by the warrior race from the planet Mandalore.**

Comment: I thought Jango Fett and his clone son were human, as were all Stormtrooper clones. He also did remove his helmet.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I didn't mention the helmet in this answer, did I?

Comment: But Boba and Jango were not from Mandalore.

Comment: It's also sometimes refereed to as Mandalorian Iron too.

Comment: @Jens You don't have to be from Mandalore to be a Mandalorian. For them, their cultural beliefs (through clans) are more important and take greater presidents over heritage or ethnicity. Jango Fett is "ousted" by the Mandalorian Government, because he sold his genetic material to make clones for war! And 'The Mandolorian' was saved by The "surviving" Mandalorians and adopted into their culture.